# Jquery Validate Assessing whether a field failed validation to use for other processing

Tags: jquery, validation, field, highlight, hidden

I am using the Jquery 'Validate' plugin.

I have a situation with a hidden 'file' form field. I have a button that triggers the file field and allows the user to select an image. An image preview is then show in a div.

All that works fine.

I have need to ensure that the file meets the required standards (type, size etc). I am trapping all my errors just fine but when i have an erronious value I need to show the error to the user with a highlighted field. The *actual* file field is hidden, therefor the logical thing to do is highlight the div that holds the thumbnail.

Highlighting a div is childs play, but I am stumped as to where (and how) I ascertain whether the specific field has failed validation and therefor manually call my highlight.

I thought of using Valid() but that calls validate() which re-runs the validation. I am trying to avoid re-calling validate multiple times. However I will take advise on this if multiple calls to validate() for custom functionality is considered a valid way of using the validate plugin.

Answers and thoughts greatly received.

Comment: What kind of validation do you use? Html5? A validation plugin?

Comment: THE JQuery validator 'Validate' plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/